# Inserting Case Statement into CREATE FUNCTION

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, pgadmin

I've been trying to insert a case statement into my create function statement and haven't had any luck. Just a heads up I am using pgadmin and postgresql. I have a table with rental movie titles, along with an integer that identifies what genre that movie falls in. I am grabbing the genre integer/ category_id from another table and wanted to transform the column data into a String representing the genre name instead of an id number for readibility. I must use a CREATE FUNCTION to transform the column.  The code i came up with is below. I am getting the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at end of input LINE 14: $$
> ^

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION idtoword(category_id INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(40)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE genreWord VARCHAR(40);
BEGIN
SELECT CASE category_id 
WHEN 12 THEN 'COMEDY'
WHEN 1 THEN 'DRAMA'
END
INTO genre
END;
$$
```

I tried multiple ways to insert the case statement into the create function. Something is wrong with my syntax. I would like the function to take a column of category id's and return the actual genre name I specify in the case statement

Comment: 1) You are missing a `;` after the fine `$$`. 2) You declare `genreWord` but then do `...INTO genre ...`. 3)  Read [Conditionals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) for how to use `CASE` or `IF` in `plpgsql`.

Answer (score 0):

Within a PostgreSQL function, try this code to transform a category ID into its corresponding genre word using a CASE statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION idtoword(category_id INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(40)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE genreWord VARCHAR(40);
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE category_id 
        WHEN 12 THEN 'COMEDY'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'DRAMA'
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
    END
    INTO genreWord;
    
    RETURN genreWord;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the correct syntax of words as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION idtoword(category_id INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(40)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE 
    genreWord VARCHAR(40);
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE category_id 
        WHEN 12 THEN 'COMEDY'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'DRAMA'
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
    END
    INTO genreWord; 
    
    RETURN genreWord;
END;
$$;
```

This you have missed as well I have added else unknown here.

You need to add Into genreWord and same as return genreWord

I hope this will help you to resolve the error!!

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are solve your problem, but I would recommend to use for so simple function SQL language instead PLPGSQL - it inline such function to the query. So it is much faster.

For example for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION idtoword_sql(category_id INTEGER)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(40)
 LANGUAGE sql
       AS $$
SELECT CASE category_id 
            WHEN 12 THEN 'COMEDY'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'DRAMA'
            END
$$
;
```

Here is explain analyze for 1M calls:

```
test=# SELECT 1000000 AS i \gset
test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT idtoword_pgsql(i) FROM generate_series(1, :i) AS i;
                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on generate_series i  (cost=0.00..260000.00 rows=1000000 width=32) (actual time=212.017..1986.623 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.127 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 4
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 7.048 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 20.609 ms, Emission 112.302 ms, Total 139.959 ms
 Execution Time: 2328.216 ms
(7 rows)

test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT idtoword_sql(i) FROM generate_series(1, :i) AS i;
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on generate_series i  (cost=0.00..15000.00 rows=1000000 width=32) (actual time=128.975..228.001 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.445 ms
 Execution Time: 267.660 ms
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a semicolon after `INTO genreWord`,
you could also modify you code by adding a `RETURN` statement to your query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION idtoword(category_id INTEGER)
RETURNS VARCHAR(40)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE 
    genreWord VARCHAR(40);
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE category_id 
        WHEN 12 THEN 'COMEDY'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'DRAMA'
    END
    INTO genreWord;

    RETURN genreWord;
END;
$$;
```